# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(n^3 \int_{n} ^{2n}\frac{x dx} {1+x^5}\right) $

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(n^3 \int_{n} ^{2n}\frac{x dx} {1+x^5}\right) $. I tried to apply the first mean value theorem for  definite integrals and then apply the squeeze theorem, but it didn't work. The answer given by the book is $\frac{7}{24}$,but I can't see how to get to it.

Comment: @Zacky Could you please show me how to do this and give me some explanations? I have seen this technique used, but I can't really grasp it. P. S. : I know what L'H is, but I don't know how to find the limit of the integral itself.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question to make sure that I fully understand this : $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (F(2n)-F(n)) =0$ because it is basically $F(\infty) - F(\infty)$?

Comment: Then the numerator's limits is $0$ because both $n$ and $2n$ $\to \infty$?

Comment: @Zachy, Unless you actually show that $\lim \int_n^{2n} \frac{x}{1+x^5} dx = 0$ your solution is not complete. Depending on the integrand function, it is not necessarily true that $\int_n^{2n} (\cdots) \to 0$. You should also edit to correct your derivative of $1/n^3$.

Comment: Sorry @Zacky I misspelled your username in the previous comment.

Answer (score 12):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(n^3 \int_{n} ^{2n}\frac{x dx} {1+x^5}\right) $$

Put  $x=nt$ and $dx=ndt$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^5\int^{2}_{1}\frac{t}{1+n^5t^5}dt$$

$$\int^{2}_{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^5t}{1+t^5n^5}dt=\int^{2}_{1}t^{-5}dt$$

Comment: Small typo last line. it should be n^5*t and the last integral should be t^-4. Otherwise, Very nice solution

Comment: @jacky You could add a comment on the correctness/possibility of exchanging limit and integral.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Rewrite this expression as
$$ \frac{\displaystyle\int_{n} ^{2n}\frac{x\,\mathrm dx} {1+x^5}}{\dfrac 1{n^3}}$$
and apply L'Hospital's rule.

For this you have to set 
$$f(y)=\int_{0} ^{y}\frac{x\,\mathrm dx} {1+x^5}$$
and compute the  derivative of the function $g(y)=f(2y)-f(y)$ with the first fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

Last, you'll need  to have an equivalent of $g'(n)$.

Answer (score 4):

For $x \in [n,2n]$:

$\dfrac{x}{x^5(1+(1/n)^5)}\le \dfrac{x}{1+x^5} \le \dfrac{x}{x^5(1+(1/2n)^5)}$

Integrate the lower bound:

$L(n):=\dfrac{1}{1+(1/n)^5}\displaystyle{ \int_{n}^{2n}}x^{-4}dx=$

$\dfrac{1}{1+(1/n)^5}(x^{-3}/(-3))\big ]^{2n}_{n}=$

$\dfrac{1}{1+(1/n)^5}(1/3)(1/n^3-1/(2n)^3)$=

$\dfrac{1}{1+(1/n)^5}\dfrac{7}{24n^3};$

Integrate the upper bound:

$U(n):=\dfrac{1}{1+(1/2n)^5}\dfrac{7}{24n^3}$.

Now consider

$n^3 L(n)\le n^3\displaystyle{\int_{n}^{2n}}\dfrac{x}{1+x^5}dx \le n^3U(n).$

Take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Simple approach. +1

Answer (score 3):

We should start by noting that

$$
0 \leq \int_n^{2n}\frac{x}{1+x^5}dx\leq \int_n^{2n} \frac{x}{1+x^4} dx=\left[\frac 12 \arctan(x^2)\right]_n^{2n}=\frac 12 (\arctan(2n)-\arctan n) \to 0.
$$

This justifies that we can apply L'Hospital's rule getting

$$
\lim n^3 \int_n^{2n}\frac{x}{1+x^5}\,dx = \lim \frac{\int_n^{2n}\frac{x}{1+x^5}\,dx}{\frac{1}{n^3}} = \lim \frac{2 \cdot \frac{2n}{1+(2n)^5}-\frac{n}{1+n^5}}{\frac{-3}{n^4}} = \frac{4}{-3 \cdot 32}- \frac{1}{-3 \cdot 1}=\frac{7}{24}.
$$